# OraOLEDB.Oracle provider is not registered on the local machine (VS 2013)

Tags: asp.net, oracle, oracle11g, oledb

I had install a Visual studio 2013 ultimate version and oracle 11g express edition (11.2.0.2.0 64 bit) in my pc.

I tried to open a existing project and try to connect the database, but it throw me the error above. as long as I refresh the database OR conn.open(), it will throw me "OraOLEDB.Oracle provider is not registered on the local machine".

Anyone has experience this issues? or any method that might help on this? I have struggle with this problem for few days.

Your comment and suggestion is much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you did not install the "OraOLEDB.Oracle" - it is not included by default.

Check your options in Oracle Universal Installer or you can download it from here [64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)

Note, since you installed 64 bit version of Oracle, you also have to compile your application as "x64", otherwise it does not work.

Comment: I have install this and tried, it is still not working. I compile my application as Any Pc.. any idea on this? herm..

Comment: Check your PATH environment variable and check if DLL is registered properly, See here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

Comment: The link given is to download ODAC for oracle, and how do I know does my dll is registered? do you have any reference on it? Thanks you so much